# Jboss EAP - Servlet not loaded

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee, jboss, web.xml

I have a war file containing:

```
META-INF
|___MANIFEST.MF
WEB-INF
|___web.xml
|___classes
    |____servlet
         |____StarterServlet.class
```

my web.xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5">

    <display-name>WAR</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <display-name>Starter Servlet</display-name>
        <servlet-name>StarterServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>servlet.StarterServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>StarterServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/starter</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

And my servlet code is:

```
package servlet;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class StarterServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public void init(ServletConfig servletConfiguration) throws ServletException {

        super.init(servletConfiguration);

        System.out.println("SERVLET STARTED!");
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        System.out.println("DOGET!");

        PrintWriter printWriter = response.getWriter();

        printWriter.println("Hello world");
    }
}
```

Also, my runtime name is: "war", so i am going to lookup for my context root with this URL:

http://localhost:8080/war/starter.

[image]

The main problem is that my servlet does not get initialized, and i can't see any trace on jboss log files,although my war gets deployed correctly.

Where am i doing it wrong?

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean servlet does not get initialized? When you go to the url /starter with your browser, what error are you getting?

Comment: A 404 error. I can see that my servlet is not initialized because the init method is not invoked and i can't see any "SERVLET STARTED!" Log inside server.log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the answer of @wirnse i got the solution.

Name and runtime name must **always** contain the extension of the file which is being deployed.

For example: application.war must have name and runtime name following this pattern:

^[a-zA-Z]+.(ear|war|jar)

**myapp.war** or **war.war**

Comment: Just some advice. There are 2 other ways to deploy a war. With the cli (there you can also use runtime-name) and to copy it into the deployments folder. With the second your context root is set to your war filename, if there is no jboss-web.xml. While development you maybe want to use your IDE for deployment. I don't know about netbeans, but in eclipse you can run your project which makes an exploded deployment to the deployments folder.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the context root to http://localhost:8080/war/ you have to add a jboss-web.xml to `WEB-INF/jboss-web.xml` with content:

```
<jboss-web>
    <context-root>war</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

Also leave the default values in `Name` and `Runtime Name` when you upload the war.

In the jboss log you should then see a message with `Registered web context: /war`